# Swift Generic Constraints on Types

Tags: swift, generics

Is it possible to define a class whose generic parameters both conform to some given type?

For example

```
protocol Foo{}
class Bar : Foo {}
class Baz : Foo {}
class Qux<T, U, V where U: T, V: T> {}

let qux = Qux<Foo, Bar, Baz>()
```

Answer (score 0):

No. Not to a type. *Type constraints* specify that a *type parameter* must inherit from a class, or conform to a protocol or protocol composition:

```
class SomeClass<TypeParameter: ProtocolOrClass>
```

Why don't you just do:

```
protocol Foo {}
class Bar: Foo {}
class Baz: Foo {}
class Qux<U: Foo, V: Foo> {}

let qux = Qux<Bar, Baz>()
```